False Color Objects by Size
I have a mesh which is clearly made up of several loose components. I want a way of applying a rainbow colour ramp to the mesh to act as a 'heat map' for component size. I would like to apply this in a systematic way to the components so that 'big' are to one end of the ramp and 'small' to the other. I can false colour components randomly easily enough, but I cannot figure out how to do this systematically by size. There must be a simple solution, but I cannot figure it out. Thanks!


If you're talking about "size" in 3D you could be talking about different things? Volume? Height? Mass? Width? I assume you mean volume?

Hi! Yes true, any of those could be metrics for size. But let's say by volume. Do you know any shader configs?

I used the GeoNodes setup from this answer to calculate the volume of your meshes. I only added the Mesh Island field node as the Group ID input for the Accumulate Field node; calculating the volume for each separate element of the mesh. Then I just mapped the range of those from 0-1 with the Map Range node.

Then you can just store that value in a Named Attribute and use that as a gradient for a color ramp node to color your meshes according to their volume.


Great answer! I found the other answer as well but had no time to really investigate it.

@GordonBrinkmann it's pretty funny cause that answer is actually a recreation of another regular stackexchange answer about how to calculate volume in code. So we're just creating a chain of answers expanding on other answers into infinity.

Yes, I've seen that  Well, keeping it up to date

Thanks for your answer @Jakemoyo! It looks like this is what I need to do, and have tried, but it is still not working for me. I am sure it is a simple problem, but I cannot figure it out. Could someone please take a quick look at my blend file and node setup? 

Looks like you don't have anything plugged into the attribute statistic node. You need to connect the Geometry input into that. I'm not switched to the newest version, so some of your nodes are coming up undefined on my end. But I'm pretty sure that's your problem.
